# Fallout 4: Does killing the Nuka-World raiders prevent exploration of the park areas?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm going to play the Nuka-World DLC for a second time, this time as a good guy aligned with the Minutemen. When I do the quest "Open Season" and kill off the raider faction leaders, does it truncate any of the other quests in the DLC?

Do I still get to open each park section via a questline... albeit now for the traders instead of the raiders? Will other questlines like the Hubologists stuff still be available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have gathered through a couple times playing is that you are still able to open all sections of the park/ turn the power back on. However there is no corresponding minute men/trader quests for the raider quests. Thus if you chose to kill the raiders any quest which is given by them will become blocked. Side quests not given by the raiders or that do not involve them as a solution will still be available to you. Thus something like the Hubologist should be perfectly accessible.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. For the record, I got "Open Season" from Mackenzie(?) in the marketplace before I met Gage at the Fizztop Grille. When I killed the first gang boss, the quest to meet him ("An Ambitious Plan") failed. After I turned in "Open Season", I did not get a quest for the power plant, but was able to get to the roof and turn it back on. Each park gives me its own quest (Star Control, etc.) when I enter it, and so far other quests have worked as well. Not sure yet if the arena quests are still available, but probably not.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to claim the other park areas as you did with the raiders.

You will still be able to explore and do all area-specific quests - as soon as you go near one of the areas, the quests will pop up. The traders will however not become a faction, so siding with them is quite a bit of an anti-climax.

Siding with the traders, you will not be able to claim the areas with flag poles as you do when siding with the raiders. Neither will you get the loot chest that the raider gang would offer you when you hand them the area.

Various minor cosmetic details will be affected depending on which side you pick: you will get different trader dialogues if you side with them, and the Raider radio channel will go offline.

I would strongly recommend siding with the raiders for the first play-through, as you'll get a whole lot more content that way. It is clearly how the DLC is meant to be played - siding with the traders isn't very interesting. It will give you one big, difficult shoot-out killing every raider in Nuka World - probably the hardest combat challenge the game offers. But when that's over, that's that.

Other Nuka World quest lines like the hubologists, the hidden Cappy, the park medals etc are not affected.

Notably however, The Minutemen and raiders are nemesis factions. So your relation with Preston will get screwed up unless you side with the traders - he will refuse to join you as companion until you do.  Similarly, you will become an enemy of Porter Gage if you side with the traders, so you will have to chose between Preston and Gage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 100% sure but I believe you wouldn't be able to anymore. Just know that my friend got locked out from so many quests after doing it, so better not.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  If you're not sure about something, it's best to not attempt to leave the question for someone else to answer.  If you have some info to contribute but not a full or confident answer, consider leaving a comment instead of an answer.  I hope you'll continue to use and contribute to Arqade.